# why non intitialized class object pointer can access pointer member and struct pointer can not access pointer variable

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct

In below program, pointer variable can be accessed through non-initialized class object but can not be accessed through non-initialized structure pointer (leads to segmentation fault) ??

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
//structure demo
struct demo
{
  int *data;
};
//class ABC
class ABC
{
    public:
   int *A;
   //default constructor 
    ABC()
   {
     cout<<"ABC constructor\n";

   }
  //display function..
  void displayA()
  {
    printf("display A\n");
  }


};

int main()
{
  ABC *obj;  //class object pointer..
  struct demo *DEMO;  //structure pointer

  printf("%u\n",obj->A);  //works properly no segmentation fault
  printf("%u\n", DEMO->data); // leading to segmentation fault..

  return 0;
}
```

I have compile and run the above program

```
g++ -o p1 p1.cpp 
./p1  
**Output:**
1831469976
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

From my analysis, any pointer only have the memory of size of word based on architecture (32 bit or 64 bit..) Hence, class object pointer will have memory for pointer not for its data member. So, how non-initialized class object pointer (obj) is able to access its data member (A) because it will not have memory.

One more thing I want to ask where the address of function are stored and how these are resolved in c/c++? I am not clear with this concept.

Comment: `struct` and `class` are the same thing, so if you think there is a difference due to that, you're on the wrong track.

Comment: Pretty useless to ask about the specific behavior of undefined behavior.

Comment: Don't make the mistake of assuming behavior is decidable simply because you observed it. Undefined behavior is just that; behavior without definition. Attempting to make sense of it is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @OP If you compiled using different options, you may get another differing behavior.  So are you willing to spend time studying that new scenario?  In other words, don't waste valuable time with this, and instead learn proper usage of the C++ language.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification. I got it. It is an undefined behaviour..

Comment: C or C++? Why both languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four pointers, and all four are uninitialized. Memory, as a whole, is either accessible or not. An uninitialized pointer thus points to either memory you are allowed to access, or not.

In your case, the `obj` pointer happens to point to a piece of memory you are allowed to read from. Thus reading the `A` pointer is valid, and it can be printed. This is however purely random - in this case you got lucky. There is no guarantee it will happen again when you run the program again, or when you run it on different machines.

Similarly, the `DEMO` pointer happens to point to a piece of memory you are not allowed to read from. Trying to do so anyway results in a segmentation fault. Again, this is purely random.

A good rule of thumb is to *always* initialize your pointers to nullptr. It makes your job a lot easier: attempting to dereference a nullptr will always crash the program (on most modern machines anyway), so you will be warned earlier that a problem exists.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution would be to  DEMO->(*data) since you declared data as a pointer. I haven't tried the code, so I might be wrong.
Still, remember that "DEMO->(*data)" is a shorthand for (*DEMO).(*data).

Now this should give you a strange random value because you didn't initialize thee pointer *data (if not a Seg Fault again).
To do so, either use dynamical allocation (with "malloc/calloc" in C or with "new" in C++, or simply declare it statically in the structure:

```
struct demo
{
  int data[NUMBER];
};
```

where NUMBER ca be any positive integer. NOTE that you don't need the * (asterisk) because you declared the pointer in array form (I assume you know that pointers and arrays are almost the same thing. If not, Google it asap. This will also answer your final question).

Hope this helps. Good luck! :)

Comment: I think you did n't get my question I think I have not explained properly. But thanks for response!!

Comment: My question is  printf("%u\n",obj->A);  // why works properly no segmentation fault?
  printf("%u\n", DEMO->data); // why leading to segmentation fault??  both are pointers right , both are trying to access pointer variable but one is working fine and other one is lading to segmentation fault.

Comment: @user1710979 you should read a good book before you decide who's right and who's not. And also read more about difference between C and C++.

Comment: He's never dereferencing the pointers inside the struct and class.The problem is that the two pointers in main() are already uninitialized.

Answer (score -2):

If you really want to test the difference, you must use the same pointer for both class & struct:

```
int main()
{
  void *p;

  printf("%u\n", ((struct demo *)p)->A);
  printf("%u\n", ((ABC *)p)->data);

  return 0;
}
```

Now both printfs try to access the same memory location (which is obviously garbage and may not exist) and from there on try to find the member.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: You do have a point. It may answer it if the outcome of both printfs is the same (I don't have a compiler at hand now), but then again, it may not be the same /)